# Go lang doing some terraform testing modules from up and running book

Tags: go, gcc, ld

Just going thru a terraform book and testing go code.  I can run simple Go fine but when I'm trying to use the terratest module with some real basic Go code I am getting this error.  Tried changing symlinks to other ld listed in the /usr/bin/.  Any help is appreciated.  Elementary OS 5.1.

```
# runtime/cgo
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.

(base) XXXXX@XXXX-Latitude-E6540:/usr/bin$ ls -la *ld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1382 May 10  2018 dh_auto_build
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35000 Jan 18  2018 fold
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Jun 18  2020 gold -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gold
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Dec 22 16:52 ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun 18  2020 ld.gold -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.gold
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Mar 26  2018 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      36 Feb  5  2018 swipl-ld -> ../lib/swi-prolog/bin/amd64/swipl-ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun 18  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gold -> x86_64-linux-gnu-    ld.gold
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 Jun 18  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3111952 Jun 18  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.gold
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Jun 18  2020 x86_64-linux-gnux32-ld -> x86_64-linux-gnux32-ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3111952 Jun 18  2020 x86_64-linux-gnux32-ld.gold
```

Go test code:

```
package test
  
import  (
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
    "testing"
)

func TestAlbExample (t *testing.T) {
    opts := &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "/home/XXXX/terraform/aws/examples/alb",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided this maybe coming from my conda installation as it does have some shared binaries in the "go env".  I removed it and bingo.  So if you have this problem definitely look there.